# Can't unmarchall elements from XML file with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to convert context of xml file to java object.

But some part is extracted ok, and some has null values.

Here is xml file:

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ EchoToken="50987" SequenceNmbr="1" Target="Production" TimeStamp="2003-11-19T19:44:10-05:00"
                        Version="2.001"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.xsd"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <POS>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <TPA_Extension>
                <PromoRatesRequired Value="false"/>
                <UserName Value="342561"/>
                <UserPassword Value="1234"/>
                <ClearCache Value="true"/>
            </TPA_Extension>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </POS>

    <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <DepartureDateTime>2015-04-13T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DUB"/>
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CDG"/>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>

    <TravelPreferences>
        <CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Economy"/>
    </TravelPreferences>

    <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" Quantity="0"/>
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
        </AirTravelerAvail>
    </TravelerInfoSummary>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

I have trouble with extracting 'OriginDestinationInformation' and 'AirTravelerAvail'.

Here is ***main()***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ rq = (OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
        System.out.println(rq);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | JAXBException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}
```

Here is output snippet:

```
originDestinationInformation=[OriginDestinationInformation{
departureDateTime=null, 
originLocation=null, 
destinationLocation=null, 
alternateLocationInfo=null, 
rph='null', 
refNumber=null}], 

travelerInfoSummary=TravelerInfoSummary{
ticketingCountryCode='null', 
specificPTCIndicator=null, 
airTravelerAvails=null}, 

echoToken='50987', 
timeStamp=2003-11-19T19:44:10-05:00, 
target='Production', 
version=2.001, 
transactionIdentifier='null', 
sequenceNmbr=1,
```

And much more interesting part `OriginDestinationInformation`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OriginDestinationInformation", propOrder = {
        "departureDateTime",
        "originLocation",
        "destinationLocation",
        "tpaExtensions",
        "alternateLocationInfo",
        "rph",
        "refNumber"
})
public static class OriginDestinationInformation extends OriginDestinationInformationType {

    @XmlElement(name = "DepartureDateTime", required = true)
    protected TimeInstantType departureDateTime;

    @XmlElement(name = "OriginLocation", required = true)
    protected OriginLocation originLocation;

    @XmlElement(name = "DestinationLocation", required = true)
    protected DestinationLocation destinationLocation;

    @Transient
    @XmlElement(name = "AlternateLocationInfo")
    protected AlternateLocationInfo alternateLocationInfo;

    @XmlElement(name = "TPA_Extensions")
    protected TPAExtensionsType tpaExtensions;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "RPH")
    protected String rph;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "RefNumber")
    protected Integer refNumber;
    // getters and setters
```

`TimeInstantType`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TimeInstantType", propOrder = {
        "value"
})
public class TimeInstantType {

    @Property("dateTime")
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    // rest of class
```

`OriginLocation`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OriginLocation")
public static class OriginLocation extends LocationType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "MultiAirportCityInd")
    protected Boolean multiAirportCityInd;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "AlternateLocationInd")
    protected Boolean alternateLocationInd;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "LocationCode")
    protected String locationCode;
```

`DestinationLocation`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DestinationLocation")
public static class DestinationLocation extends LocationType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "MultiAirportCityInd")
    protected Boolean multiAirportCityInd;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "AlternateLocationInd")
    protected Boolean alternateLocationInd;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "LocationCode")
    protected String locationCode;
```

---

and for list of objects `TravelerInfoSummary`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TravelerInfoSummary", propOrder = {
        "airTravelerAvails",
        "ticketingCountryCode",
        "specificPTCIndicator"
})
public static class TravelerInfoSummary extends TravelerInfoSummaryType {

    @Embedded
    @XmlElement(name = "AirTravelerAvail")
    protected List<AirTravelerAvail> airTravelerAvails;
```

`AirTravelerAvail`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AirTravelerAvail")
public class AirTravelerAvail {

    @Embedded
    @XmlElement(name = "PassengerTypeQuantity")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "AirTravelerAvail")
    protected List<PassengerTypeQuantity> passengerTypeQuantities;
```

I couldn't figure out what is wrong here. I tried

> @XmlElementWrapper(name = "AirTravelerAvail")

for list of objects but it keep getting `null`.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: The root element is 'OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ', i do not see any class that maps to that? Thats the class that needs to be passed to jaxbcontext, with others as properties

Comment: @maress I have this class and it is unmarshalled ok.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I hate JAXB!

That said, i literally have to specify

> @XmlElemnt(namespace = "namespace")

on every element of a class. JAXB simply does not assign the default namespace to the current xml dom.

By default, JAXB seems to work with `ElementFormDefault="unqualified"` and `AttributeFormDefault="qualified"` (I may have confused this), but this makes it unmarshall the root element, considering only attributes as belonging to the default-namespace.

If the namespace has a prefix e.g. `xmlns:ns="namespace"`, then **JAXB** will correctly marshall elements as to belonging to this namespace.

If you have control over xml, simply have a prefix to the default namespace, like

> xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"

If you dont, make sure to have

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
```

on every element that is not an attribute.

```
package com.anosym.stackoverflow.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import static com.anosym.stackoverflow.stackoverflow.Main.calendarString;
import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD;

@XmlRootElement(name = "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ", namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "EchoToken")
    private String echoToken;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "SequenceNmbr  ")
    private int sequenceNmbr;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Target")
    private String target;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TimeStamp")
    private Calendar timeStamp;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Version")
    private String version;
    @XmlElement(name = "POS", namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
    private POS pos;
    @XmlElement(name = "OriginDestinationInformation", namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
    private OriginDestinationInformation destinationInformation;

    public OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ(String echoToken, int sequenceNmbr, String target, Calendar timeStamp, String version,
                                 POS pos, OriginDestinationInformation destinationInformation) {
        this.echoToken = echoToken;
        this.sequenceNmbr = sequenceNmbr;
        this.target = target;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.version = version;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.destinationInformation = destinationInformation;
    }

    public OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ{"
                + "echoToken=" + echoToken + ", "
                + "sequenceNmbr=" + sequenceNmbr + ", "
                + "target=" + target + ", "
                + "timeStamp=" + calendarString(timeStamp) + ", "
                + "version=" + version + ", "
                + "pos=" + pos + ", "
                + "destinationInformation=" + destinationInformation + '}';
    }

}

package com.anosym.stackoverflow.stackoverflow;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

import static javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD;

@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class POS {

    @XmlElement(name = "TPA_Extension", namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "TPA_Extensions", namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
    private List<TPAExtension> tpaExtensions;

    public POS(List<TPAExtension> tpaExtensions) {
        this.tpaExtensions = tpaExtensions;
    }

    public POS() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "POS{" + "tpaExtensions=" + tpaExtensions + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: I added namespace to the xml file. Without it couldn't work `xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"`. But you saw which output It got. I couldn't understand why this happen. Can you give some suggestions how to parse **from xml to objects without JAXB**? Which approach will be better to parse this `request.xml`.